# Creating a flag / filtering data for multiple columns - is.na, grpl?

Tags: r, filtering

I have a dataframe that opertes like this:

```
col1 = c("NA","code1", "NA", "NA", "NA")
col2 = c("NA","code1", "NA", "code3", "NA")
col3 = c("NA","NA", "NA", "code3", "code4")
col4 = c("NA","NA", "NA", "code3", "code4")
add= c("123 fake st","pobox 1", "pobox 2", "pobox 3", "123 real st")

df = data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,add)
```

If it has any value in any of the first 4 columns, then that is fine; if it has no value in any of the first 4 columns (all NA) and the address (c=add) is a pobox, then it makes enough sense for the data to be missing; but if it has no value in the first 4 columns and the address isn't a pobox then I need to flag it to look at in more detail.

I can get a true/false statement on any one of the columns:

```
df$flag <- is.na(df$col1)
```

I can do a search for po box:

```
df$flag <- grepl("po", df$add)
```

I cannot for the life of me combine even just the na checks, let alone all of them; this is the latest version of what I have tried:

```
ocracoke_geo$flag <- if((is.na(ocracoke_geo$mail_parno) &
                           is.na(ocracoke_geo$mail_altparno) &
                           is.na(ocracoke_geo$site_parno) &
                           is.na(ocracoke_geo$site_altparno)
                        1, 0)
```

Please help!

Comment: Just to verify: did you mean `NA` instead of `"NA"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data includes the literal string `"NA"`, then

```r
rowSums(df[,1:4] == "NA") == 4 & !grepl("pobox", df$add)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If your data instead has the `NA` literals, then

```r
df[df=="NA"] <- NA # just to adjust your sample data, not required if already `NA` literals

rowSums(is.na(df[,1:4])) == 4 & !grepl("pobox", df$add)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```